# Как центрировать окно приложения в PyQt6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt6, qtimer

Я хочу разместить главное окно приложения ровно по центру экрана.

Я попробовал все (как мне кажется) способы из интернета, но окно все равно оказывается левее и выше середины моего экрана.

Как это исправить?

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, \
    QApplication, QWidget


app = QApplication([])

def center_window(window):
    qr = window.frameGeometry()
    cp = window.screen().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    window.move(qr.topLeft())


window = QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('TestWindow')
window.setFixedSize(200, 70)

line = QLineEdit()
line.setPlaceholderText('Введите что-нибудь')
label = QLabel('Это поле для ввода')

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(label)
layout.addWidget(line)

window.setLayout(layout)
center_window(window)

window.show()
app.exec()
```

---

Но при этом, я получаю такой результат:

[image: Результат]

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick, Да, извиняюсь за оплошность. Добавил пример и результат, который я получаю

Comment: Где конкретные данные что окно левее и выше? Как докажете? Линейкой что ли мерили? Судя по тому что вы делаете вы пытаетесь левый верхний угол окна приложения поставить в центр дисплея.

Comment: @Александр, ну во-первых, глазомер у меня достаточно хороший, хотя тут хорошо видно, что окно правее нужного положения. Но, естественно, полагаться только на это нельзя, в моем мониторе есть функция Crosshair, которая включает прицел ровно посередине экрана. Так вот, к слову об левом верхнем угле, окно не оказывалось там никаким конкретным местом, оно было расположено непонятным образом, без какой-либо привязки к месту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, у вас хорошее зрение.

Попробуйте дать окну отрисоваться, а затем переместите окно.

```
'''
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, \
    QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget
from PyQt6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
'''
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, \
    QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


class Window(QWidget):                
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('TestWindow')
        self.setFixedSize(1356, 684)                             #(200, 70)

        self.line = QLineEdit()
        self.line.setPlaceholderText('Введите что-нибудь')
        self.label = QLabel('Это поле для ввода')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.line)
        
#        self.center_window()                          # !!! это ваше.                               
        QTimer.singleShot(10, self.center_window)      # !!! попробуйте так !!! <----
        

    def center_window(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()

        cp = self.screen().availableGeometry().center()
#        cp = QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry().center()
#        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()

        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
        print(f'{qr.topLeft()}') 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
#    w.resize(1356, 684)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: @Axaneron что не так?

Comment: Добрый день! Большое спасибо за ответ. Это намного больше похоже на правду) С помощью ``QTimer`` окно оказывалось чуть выше середины, но при помощи просто ``self.center_window`` оно оказалось точно посередине. Благодарен вам!)

Comment: @Axaneron пожалуйста.